# ECS Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup config-service on 10.0.0.2:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, microservices, amazon-ecs

There are two services: `config-service` and `discovery-service`

Dockerfile of `config-service` :

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
ENV APP_FILE config-service.jar
ENV APP_HOME /app
EXPOSE 8088
COPY build/libs/$APP_FILE $APP_HOME/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["exec java -jar $APP_FILE --spring.profiles.active=native,docker"]
```

Dockerfile of `discovery-service` :

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

ENV DOCKERIZE_VERSION v0.6.1
RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz

ENV APP_FILE discovery-service.jar
ENV APP_HOME /app
EXPOSE 8061
COPY build/libs/$APP_FILE $APP_HOME/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["exec dockerize -timeout 5m -wait tcp://config-service:8088 java -jar $APP_FILE --spring.profiles.active=docker"]
```

Therefore, `discovery-service` waits until `config-service` is connected.
There are no problem while running on local and docker.

For my docker running on localhost, the successful message from `discovery-service` should be:

```
Problem with dial: dial tcp 172.22.0.2:8088: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s

Connected to tcp://config-service:8088
```

However once I run on AWS ECS, `config-service` runs perfectly as expected; `discovery-service` keeps prompting the error per second:

```
Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup config-service on 10.0.0.2:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
```

Here are setting on ECS:

**Task Definition**

I almost set all configs as default. I leave empty for Task role and Task execution role. Only Network mode and compatibilities have set. `awsvpc` and `Bridge` have been tried for Network mode, and `EC2` and `FARGATE` have been tried for compatibilities.

**Container inside Task Definition**

`Port mappings` and `Hostname` for `NETWORK SETTINGS` are set. `8088` for `config-service` and `8061` for `discovery-service`

**Cluster**

`EC2 Linux + Networking` template. `m5d.large` EC2, Security group inbound rule is set to be `8088` and `8061` respectively.

**Service**

Service is created for Cluster, I use the most basic setting. Service type is `DAEMON` without Load balancing or other add-ons.

Please let me know what's wrong with my setting on ECS. Thank you!